# Angularjs divs blocking semanticui css

Tags: css, angularjs, semantic-ui

i have two *.event* div in *.ui* div. First div is dynamic and angular-js wrap this loop with *.ng-scope*. This divs blocking that css selectors in semantic.ui

```
.ui.feed>.event>.label img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 500rem;
}
```

if change > operator with " " like,

```
.ui.feed .event>.label img {
```

It's work. But i'm not sure replacing all semantic selectors is good idea. Any other way, without move *.ui* in loop?

```
<div class="ui feed ng-scope">
    <div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="feed in feeds">
        <div video-added="" class="" info="info">
            <div class="event">
                <div class="label">
                    <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/small/matt.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui fitted divider"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: feed in feeds -->
    <div class="event">
        <div class="label">
            <img src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/small/matt.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Worse think is semantic.ui selectors are more complex than ".ui.feed > .event". Angularjs div elements broke all grids.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. The first `.event` div is a descendant of `.ui`, but not a direct child, so you can't use `>` which is used only for direct children. So leave the `>` out. This is also your own answer, so then the problem is solved.

Comment: semantic.ui selectors are more complex than ".ui.feed > .event". Like ".ui.grid > * {" or ".ui.grid > .column:not(.row)". I'm sure, semantic developers used ">" operator for necessary reasons. So if i try to change ">" on grid class pages look like running on internet explorer 4